# NGINX returns a 302 error page instead of make a 302 redirect

Tags: nginx

I have this section on my server block:

```
    location /mycoolurl {
             rewrite /mycoolurl(.*) $1 redirect;
    }
```

When someone try in the browser
http://coolserver/mycoolurl/ it try to redirect to:

http://coolserver/

Also, everything like
http://coolserver/mycoolurl/foo/bar redirect to:

http://coolserver/foo/bar

However, if I try to access
http://coolserver/mycoolurl
It shows a default nginx error page with:

```
302 - Found
```

The expected behaviour is a 302 redirect to http://coolserver instead of showing an error page with this, as it is not an error.

How to get the expected behaviour?

Comment: Show us all the response headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access /mycoolurl your regular expression (.*) captures nothing. Thus Nginx returns an empty value in the "Location" header together with 302 response code. Most browsers consider this combination incorrect and display an error.

To prevent this, you need to modify your rewrite rule, for example, this way:

```
location /mycoolurl {
    rewrite /mycoolurl/?(.*)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```